# PHP Page Error | Fatal error: The encoded file /home/*edited*l/index.php has expired. in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php

this is the error I get when I load my page.

**Scenario:

1. download Pinstatic script.
2. copy to /home/...
3. Install IonCube
   3.1 Edit php.ini like so:

   [Zend] 
   zend_extension="/home/administratorsix/public_html/ioncube/ioncube_loader_lin_5.4.so" 
   zend_extension_ts="/home/administratorsix/ioncube/public_html/ioncube_loader_lin_5.4_ts.so"

   3.2
   Installation of IonCube succeded
   Loader Installed
   The ionCube Loader version 5.1.2 for PHP 5.4 is already installed and encoded files should run without problems.
4. Load the page and got this error:

Fatal error: 
The encoded file /home/administratorsix/public_html/index.php has expired. in Unknown on line 0

Questions :

Why I get this message and how can I fix it ?

Please help ! Thank you !
Gabriel

Answer (score 0):

It might think the document has expired if your system's clock is set incorrectly, check your system time. The other reason that might cause this, is if you uploaded the encoded file in `ASCII` mode rather than `BINARY` via FTP. Not sure if ionCube does this, but the encoder's license might actually be expired (or the script might be encoded with the trial encoder that lasts for 36 hours).
If neither works, contact the vendor of the php script for further help.